# stopping a powershell script mid-code not working

Tags: powershell, winforms, exit

My Script uses Windows Forms and I got a Cancel Button in one of the windows. If I click the button just nothing happens and the script goes on like nothing happend. Looks like the `exit` just isn't working. Here is the code of the cancel button:

```
$connectcancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$connectcancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(197.5, 225)
$connectcancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$connectcancelButton.Text = 'Abbrechen'
$connectcancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$connectcancelButton.Add_Click({
    exit
})
$connectform.Controls.Add($connectcancelButton)
```

This part is like in ln 75 of 400 and i would like to avoid an if-statement which goes all the way to the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Form.Close()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close) to close the owning form object:

```
$connectcancelButton.Add_Click({
    param($Sender,$EArgs)

    # obtain reference to the form owning the button control
    $owningForm = $Sender.Parent
    # close form
    $owningForm.Close()
})
```